# Is it fully possible to install Ubuntu on a "slave HDD", by using Wubi, I've Windows 7 as primary HDD?

Tags: installation, wubi

Is it fully possible to install Ubuntu on a slave HDD, by using Wubi,  I've Windows 7 as primary HDD ?

I mean will Wubi installation go normal on "slave HDD", like no blue screens of death , or any mishappenings n accidents like data loss etc..

I've HDD structure of 2 X 1TB of 2 HDDs.

```
Disk0
C: Windows 7 - 40GB
D: Store (for data n all) - 891 GB

Disk1
E: HDD1 - (for backups mostly) - 931GB
```

Now what I want is to make a 30GB partition from E: (Disk 1 "slave") and install Ubuntu there using Wubi.

So Will WUBI be able to install Ubuntu on "slave HDD" normally, without any fatal mishappenings or accidents or ny kind data loss.

Comment: Wubi installs Ubuntu on a file so, you don't need to make partitions for it. Also Wubi is intended for you to try Ubuntu and if you like it make a partition(s) and install Ubuntu properly.

Comment: @Nick - please register your account and then click the link at the bottom of the page to ask for both of your unregistered accounts to be merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Wubi aim is to enable existing Windows users, unacquainted with Linux, to try Ubuntu without risking any data loss (due to disk formatting or partitioning mistakes). It can also safely uninstall Ubuntu from within Windows.

Wubi (Windows-based Ubuntu Installer) is an official Windows-based free software installer for Ubuntu, which installs the software on an existing Windows partition, thus without need for partitioning.

Wubi adds an entry to the Windows boot menu which allows the user to run Linux. Ubuntu is installed within a file in the Windows file system (`c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`), as opposed to being installed within its own partition. This file is seen by Linux as a real hard disk. Wubi also creates a swap file in the Windows file system (`c:\ubuntu\disks\swap.disk`), in addition to the memory of the host machine. This file is seen by Ubuntu as additional RAM.

**Limitation of Wubi:**

Compared with a regular installation, a Wubi installation faces some limitations. Hibernation is not supported and the filesystem is more vulnerable to hard reboots.[1] Also, if the Windows drive is unmounted uncleanly (Windows crash, power failure, etc.), Ubuntu will not be able to mount the Windows drive and boot until Windows has successfully booted and shut down. If the Windows system cannot be booted after the crash, the user also cannot boot Ubuntu.

Performance related to hard-disk access is also slightly slower, more so if the disk image file is fragmented, on a Wubi install compared to a normal one.

Since Wubi installs root.disk on top of the Windows file system which could technically become corrupted and even prevent Windows from booting, running `chkdsk /r` (may take a significant amount of time to run) to fix the damaged file system and shutting down Windows cleanly may help.

Comment: OK ! So if that means since wubi installs it to a "File" as such does that also means one can't install 3rd party ubuntu linux applications like compiz, emerald , etc..

Comment: @nick yes we can install other 3rd pary applications by adding their Repositories in the system settings/software source.and more information on repositries https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As stated Wubi has some of it's own limitations, like some stated above.

So can Ubuntu be installed on a "slave HDD" , "Without Wubi installer, with normal installer" . I mean Will Ubuntu Operating system work OK ! from slave HDD ?

also I'vent enabled RAID yet on my 2 X 1 TB HDDs for I heard somewhere Ubuntu probs with RAID. so I've RAID disabled on my system. and NO RAID drivers 've been installed yet in windows.